# Single-click to open applications in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mouse

Was just wondering if this was an option in GNOME anymore. I know they were taking away settings like crazy there for awhile (hell I even had to use the console to add minimize and maximize buttons back to my desktop-- crazy), and I wouldn't at all be surprised if they got rid of it. I'd appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this setting:

1. Open files explorer and select preferences:

   [image]
2. Go to behaviour tab and select `single click option`:

   [image]
3. Now test it.

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't realize they moved the preferences to the panel's little touchscreen button

Comment: Welcome, we all have to get lost some times :)